# How to change the default color theme of a Vuetify button?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

what i need is change the default color of a button if a developer write a button like this

```
<v-btn>Aceptar</v-btn>
```

vue render a default button [image: default]

i know i can do this

```
export default new Vuetify({
    theme: {
        themes: {
            light: {
                
              }
        }
    }
});
```

but i need vue render a simple button with a custom color like this

`<v-btn>Ok</v-btn>` ----(render)---> [image: default]

i know can override css but i dont know where do this

```
.theme--light.v-btn.v-btn--has-bg {
    background-color: #4b53b9;
}
```

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

As you can create Your own theme with your wanted colors, the *easiest* way is just to add a class with your wanted styles and apply them to the button:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {}
  }
})

Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

```css
/* needs to use !important to override the default theme styles */
.my-theme-btn-class {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/0.15.4/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/0.15.4/vuetify.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<v-app id="app" toolbar--fixed toolbar>

  <v-btn class="my-theme-btn-class">Clear</v-btn>

</v-app>
```

Which will work fine.

---

As per your comment, you want to use SCSS logic for it. As you need your custom color, `plain` and `block` - just add those styles to the `.v-btn` class:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {}
  }
})

Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

```css
.btn {
  /* .v-btn--block styles */
  display: flex !important;
  flex: 1 0 auto !important;
  min-width: 100% !important;
  max-width: auto !important;
  
  /* and your custom colors */
  background-color: #4b53b9 !important;
}

.btn::before {
  /* .v-btn--plain:before styles */
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/0.15.4/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/0.15.4/vuetify.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<v-app id="app">

  <v-btn>Clear</v-btn>

</v-app>
```

Comment: yes i know will work but i am looking is instead of write <v-btn class="primary" block plain>Ok</v-btn> to get the blue button i need write <v-btn>ok<v-btn> and get the same blue plain button i think the solution is with sass

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to create a CSS class if you just need to change one button's background color.

You can apply `color` prop directly to a button component. This way, by example:

```js
<v-btn color="#4b53b9">
  Aceptar
</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 1):

So there could be two scenarios to achieve this requirement as per the use case.

1. You just want to change `<v-btn>` default color in one place. Then, I will suggest you to make this change inline by using `color` attribute.

   For Example **:**

   ```
   <v-btn color="#4b53b9">Button</v-btn>
   ```
2. If you want to change `<v-btn>` at all the places in your application wherever you used this button. Then, I will suggest you to override the `.v-btn` color by make this style change at global `.css` file.

   For Example **:**

   ```
   .v-btn {
       background-color: #4b53b9 !important;
   }
   ```

Comment: do you think is possible to write "<v-btn></v-btn>" insted of this "<v-btn   block   color="primary"   large   outlined ></v-btn>" to get the same button. i think is with SASS

Comment: In this case you can follow my 2nd solution which I added in an answer.